# Run the report in APEX and see if it is returning rows

Tags: apex, reporting, reports-api

As I stated in the headline, I want to be able to run the report and see if It is returning rows or not. (empty or has data)

The background is that I am exporting reports data. So I need to know when the report is empty, in order to avoid the export of the empty report because I end up with HTML data in the report instead of rows. I want to avoid that and make it more user friendly.

I investigated a below result from Reports.ReportResults object and did not found anything that could be used as a solid flag for this case.

```
Reports.ReportResults results = Reports.ReportManager.runReport(reportId, true);
System.debug(results);
```

Any help or idea would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried simply calling `results.getHasDetailRows()`?

Comment: Yes, it is returning true even if the report is empty.

Comment: Check this https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/280847/apex-class-to-create-a-set-of-record-ids-from-a-salesforce-report

Answer (score 0):

// Get the fact map from the report results - assuming it is a tabular report
Reports.ReportFactWithDetails factDetails =
(Reports.ReportFactWithDetails)results.getFactMap().get('T!T');

system.debug('results '+factDetails);

//get row size
integer rowCount = factDetails.getRows().size();

// Get the field value from the first data cell of the first row of the report
Reports.ReportDetailRow detailRow = factDetails.getRows()[0];

System.debug(detailRow.getDataCells()[0].getLabel());